# Direct STDERR when opening pipe in perl

Tags: r, perl, pipe, execution

I am using `open( my $command_out, "-|", $command_string )` to execute a command and process its output on the fly  (not having to wait for the command to finish first, as in `system()`).

I noticed that when I call some R scripts this way, some of R messages are printed to the screen (e.g. `Loading required package: ...`). I guess this is because R sends this output to stderr (? although these are not really errors).

Is it possible to direct this output too to `$command_out` when `open()`-ing so the screen will remain clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IPC::Run`](http://p3rl.org/IPC::Run) to capture STDOUT and STDERR separately. The `pump` function gives you the output on the fly.

Answer (score 10):

Say your R program is

```
#! /usr/bin/env r

require(Hmisc)

cat(argv[1], "\n")
```

which turns out to be surprisingly chatty:

```
$ ./prog.r foo
Loading required package: Hmisc
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: stats
Loading required package: utils
Loading required package: graphics
Loading required package: splines

Attaching package: 'Hmisc'


    The following object(s) are masked from package:survival :

     untangle.specials 


    The following object(s) are masked from package:base :

     format.pval,
     round.POSIXt,
     trunc.POSIXt,
     units 

foo
```

From here, you could discard the standard error or merge it with another stream.

### Discarding the standard error

One way to discard the standard error is to use a shell redirect of `2>/dev/null`. This is a general mechanism, and 2 is the [standard error's file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29). For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $command_out, "-|", "./prog.r foo 2>/dev/null"
  or die "$0: could not start prog.r";

while (<$command_out>) {
  print "got: $_";
}
```

The shell will also process [backtick or `qx//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) expressions

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

(my $command_out = `./prog.r foo 2>/dev/null`) =~ s/^/got: /mg;
print $command_out;
```

and a scalar command passed to [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

system("./prog.r foo 2>/dev/null") == 0
  or warn "$0: prog.r exited " . ($? >>8);
```

For all of these, the output is

```
$ ./prog.pl 
got: foo
```

But sometimes you *don't* want the shell putting its grubby mitts on your command. Maybe it contains shell metacharacters or quotes that you don't want to deal with escaping. This is when a [safe pipe-open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens) is useful:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $pid = open my $command_out, "-|";
die "$0: fork: $!" unless defined $pid;

if ($pid == 0) {
  # child
  open STDERR, ">", "/dev/null" or die "$0: open: $!";
  exec "./prog.r", "foo & bar"  or exit 1;  # STDERR silent now
}

while (<$command_out>) {
  print "got: $_";
}

close $command_out or warn "$0: prog.r exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

Opening a handle on `"-|"` forks a child and connects the child's standard output to that handle. Like [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html), it returns 0 to the child, a non-zero process identifier to the parent, or the undefined value on failure.

In the child, we first redirect `STDERR` to `/dev/null` and then use [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) to replace the child with our R program. Note that we passed the command in list form to bypass the shell:

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, calls [execvp(3)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) with the arguments in LIST.

Because we can't see the standard error any longer, it's important to explicitly `close $command_out` to check that the child ran happily. Otherwise, you'd get a puzzling silent failure.

Sample run:

```
$ ./prog.pl 
got: foo & bar
```

### Merge `STDERR` into `STDOUT`

To see the standard error on your handle, use `2>&1` instead, *e.g.*,

```
open my $command_out, "-|", "./prog.r foo 2>&1" or die;
```

With a safe pipe-open, `dup` the standard error onto the standard output:

```
if ($pid == 0) {
  # child
  open STDERR, ">&", \*STDOUT  or die "$0: open: $!";
  exec "./prog.r", "foo & bar" or die "$0: exec: $!";
}
```

The [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) documentation covers this:

> You may also, in the Bourne shell tradition, specify an EXPR beginning with `>&`, in which case the rest of the string is interpreted as the name of a filehandle (or file descriptor, if numeric) to be duped (as [dup(2)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html)) and opened.

Even though you can see the standard error this way, it's still a good idea to check the child's exit status with `close`.

Now *everything* arrives over `$command_out`:

```
got: Loading required package: Hmisc
got: Loading required package: methods
got: Loading required package: survival
got: Loading required package: stats
got: Loading required package: utils
got: Loading required package: graphics
got: Loading required package: splines
got: 
got: Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
got: 
got: 
got:    The following object(s) are masked from package:survival :
got: 
got:     untangle.specials 
got: 
got: 
got:    The following object(s) are masked from package:base :
got: 
got:     format.pval,
got:     round.POSIXt,
got:     trunc.POSIXt,
got:     units 
got: 
got: foo & bar
```

Answer (score 5):

An easy way is to append 2>&1 to $command_string, but whether or not this works will depend on your shell.  (eg, the shell that interprets $command_string)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could redirect STDERR to STDOUT for the whole program?

```
*STDERR = *STDOUT;
open( my $command.... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do fork & exec yourself:

```
pipe R, W; # note: R and W have CLOEXEC set
if (fork == 0) {
    # child #
    open STDERR, '>&W';
    exec qw/ls -lrtac/, $ARGV[0];
    die 'not reached';
}
# parent #
close W;
while (<R>) { do_something }
close R;
wait;
```

}